# Multiple Sets of Sets of ORs

Tags: javascript

I have a feeling this isn't possible?  I'm trying to check sets of conditions here and my tests should be passing after I moved a couple of those sets out of 2 other methods and into this if statement below as to combine all the checks into one if statement:

```
 if ((move.coordinates.x === 0 && move.coordinates.y === 0 ||
        move.coordinates.x === 0 && move.coordinates.y === 1 ||
        move.coordinates.x === 0 && move.coordinates.y === 2) 
        ||

        (move.coordinates.x === 1 && move.coordinates.y === 0 ||
        move.coordinates.x === 1 && move.coordinates.y === 1 ||
        move.coordinates.x === 1 && move.coordinates.y === 2) 
        ||

        (move.coordinates.x === 2 && move.coordinates.y === 0 ||
        move.coordinates.x === 2 && move.coordinates.y === 1 ||
        move.coordinates.x === 2 && move.coordinates.y === 2))
   {
      ...then do something
   }
```

Doesn't seem the parens are making a difference here in separating out the conditional sets.

I'm trying to trim down on duplicate code  I had those 3 sets in different methods where the logic was mostly the same, but checked for different states.

So I pasted in the two other state sets (sets meaning the group of 3 ors that make up a given state) and trying to check these 3 rows basically in one method instead of splitting out into 3 to cut down dup code.

Comment: As already noted, the combined test simply checks if both `x` and `y`  properties have an integer value of 0, 1 or 2.
Is this is not the basis for excecuting the "do something" branch then simply recode to suite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplifying the notation, you have

```
(x == 0 && y == 0    ||    x == 0 && y == 1    ||    x == 0 && y == 2)
||
(x == 1 && y == 0    ||    x == 1 && y == 1    ||    x == 1 && y == 2)
||
(x == 2 && y == 0    ||    x == 2 && y == 1    ||    x == 2 && y == 2)
```

Since the operator `||` is associative, you can remove the parentheses.

And then you can use the distributive property to group the `x`.

```
x == 0 && (y == 0 || y == 1 || y == 2) ||
x == 1 && (y == 0 || y == 1 || y == 2) ||
x == 2 && (y == 0 || y == 1 || y == 2)
```

And even use the distributive property again

```
(x == 0 || x == 1 || x == 2) && (y == 0 || y == 1 || y == 2)
```

Finally, you can store the allowed values in an array and use `indexOf` to avoid repeating the variables:

```
var values = [0, 1, 2];
values.indexOf(x) >= 0 && values.indexOf(y) >= 0;
```

Comment: so you're not using === ?

Comment: @WTF The values of `move.coordinates.x` and `.y` should always be numbers, so there's no need to worry about loose vs strict comparison.

Comment: @WTF That was part of the simplification of the notation. To be safer, you can use `===`.

Answer (score 3):

you can use logical rules that cover all the possibilities you allow. if you look at the repeating values in your code, you see that you are trying to exhaust all combinations of x values 0,1,2 with combinations of y values 0,1,2. so if you make a rule that will encompass x values from 0 to 2 and the same with y values from 0 to 2, you can simplify your if statement like the example below.

```
var coordx = move.coordinates.x;
var coordy = move.coordinates.y;
if ((coordx >= 0 && coordx <= 2) && (coordy >= 0 && coordy <=2)) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: crap I wish I could vote both your answers as the answer...nice

Answer (score 0):

One issue I see with your code is the order of operations (take a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) to see the basics), consider using more brackets to be as explicit as possible. It looks like you want to do this:

```
 if (( (move.coordinates.x === 0 && move.coordinates.y === 0) ||
    (move.coordinates.x === 0 && move.coordinates.y === 1) ||
    (move.coordinates.x === 0 && move.coordinates.y === 2)) 
    ||
    ...
```

But, if you want to be a little more efficient and clear, I would recommend reformatting your logic with nested `if` statements:

```
if (x==0 || x==1 || x==2)
{
  if(y==0 || y==1 || y==2)
  {
    do something...
```